# Sha1 signature of saved file and source FileStreamResult are different

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, encryption, sha

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 app where users can generate a PDF file. This PDF file is created from an HTML view using iTextSharp.

I want to ensure that users don't manipulate the original PDF, so it's secured. I also want to be able to identify any forgery, so when the document is generated I store it's sha1 signature on database.

I create this signature from the FileStreamResult returned from the method that creates de PDF file. This FileStreamResult is just later returned to the browser, where the PDF file is shown.

My problem is that, after saving the PDF file to disk the sha1 signature of this file is different from the one on the database.

Also... if I generate exactly the same document in Firefox and in Chrome, when I save them to disk both have different signatures.

Keep in mind that I'm creating once and again the document, with the same process, same data and same filename (once I check the signature I write it down and delete the file to try with the other browser).

I suspect that browsers' PDF plugins are adding some type of comment inside the stream, invisible to the user, that makes each file different from the other (and from the original FileStreamResult whose signature I stored on DB).

I wonder if anyone know other causes than could be causing this result and if there is any way to get the correct signature on my database.

Any insight on this matter will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use real digital signatures: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Comment: Have you tried to compare the files obtained from the different browsers to check what is the difference? The PDF is not a text format so you will have to use binary diff but at least you will have an approximate locations where the files differ and may be you will be able to pin-point what causes it.

Comment: *Keep in mind that I'm creating once and again the document, with the same process, same data and same filename* - if you create it multiple times, that most likely happens at different points in time. The creation time is a property added by most PDFs generating libraries. At least this will differ. Furthermore IDs often are generated, and they are likely to differ, too.

Comment: @mkl good point. Same document, with same data and name saved from within same browser at different moments generates different signatures. Seems I'll have to go for a real digital signature, as Bruno Lowagie proposes...